# Swapping "Home" and "End" functionallity under windows 10 depending on current language being edited

Tags: keyboard

I bought a Lenovo Yoga 720 which has low amount of keyboard keys. Therefore, they merged "Home" key with the left arrow key and "End" key with the right arrow key, triggering their functionality while pressing the "Fn" key too.

Although it's comfortable enough with text editing in English, it's Really bad UX to edit RTL languages such as Hebrew like this.

Is there a way flip between "Home" and "End" functionality depending on current language being edited?